# Column based search using angular filter pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, pipe, angular7

[Below is my table view. Each column is having search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igkGd.png)

Based on text I type in particular column only that column needs to be searched.

Problem I am facing is:
When I type in one column same text is appearing in other columns also. To resolve this i have used following code:

```
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let head of headElements; let i = index" scope="col">
                <h5 class="text-color">{{head}}</h5>
                <div class="md-form mb-0">
                    <input [(ngModel)]="searchText[i]" type="text" class="form-control" 
                      id="search_{{i}}" mdbInput />
                    <label for="search_{{i}}">Search</label>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
```

By giving `[(ngModel)]="searchText[i]"` or `[(ngModel)]="searchText[head]"` I can type different text in different input box.

I am not able to get the text typed in  filter : searchText;

Below is my code to view table data

```
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let el of elements | filter : searchText; let i = index" mdbWavesEffect>
            <td class="p-2" *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex"
                scope="row">{{el.firstName}} {{el.middleName}} {{el.lastName}}</td>
            <td class="p-2" *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">
                {{el.mobileNumber}}</td>
            <td class="p-2" *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">
                {{el.joiningYear}}</td>
            <td class="p-2" *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">
                {{el.emailId}}</td>
            <td class="p-2" *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">
                {{el.designation}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Next i have declared `searchText: any = [];` in conponent.ts file or else it is giving error undefined

Last is my filter pipe code

```
  if (!employees || !searchTerm) {
    return employees;
  }
  return employees.filter(employee =>
    employee.mobileNumber.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1);

}
```

Comment: Hi @Talha, could you please put this in stackblitz will be easy to check the issue.

Comment: @SatishPai I am using my local rest service to get employee data. So i was not able to configure the project fully. here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pl8mua

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the filter pipe on `<tr>` element, try listening to the change event on your `<input>` element.

```
<tr>
        <th *ngFor="let head of headElements; let i = index" scope="col">
            <h5 class="text-color">{{head}}</h5>
            <div class="md-form mb-0">
                <input [(ngModel)]="searchText[i]" (change)="filterElements(searchText[i])" type="text" class="form-control" 
                  id="search_{{i}}" mdbInput />
                <label for="search_{{i}}">Search</label>
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
```

In the component class:

```
private elementsCopy = Object.assign({}, this.elements);
public filterElements(searchTerm){
    if (!this.elementsCopy || !searchTerm) {
        return this.elementsCopy ;
      }
  return this.elementsCopy.filter(employee =>
    employee.mobileNumber.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1);

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think this will work as we will be sending data on change. I will try it and let you know. But I need to use pipe for it.